# Debugging Spring Security Filter Chain

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using a custom implemented SSO in my app which is using Spring.
(Recently I was upgrading my app to Spring 5.2.5 and Java 11.)

At final stage of that SSO process, a URL like below is posted which bypasses authentication/login page and opens main page.

```
http://localhost:8181/MyApp/j_spring_security_check?tokenId=999a1ec9-d92a-4a5e-a7ec-a8985c421000
```

But instead of opening main page it directs me to

```
access-denied-handler error-page="/ui/ordinary/noauthorization.xhtml"
```

But when I look at Spring debug logs, I realize that `permitAll` is matched. No access denied occured.

How can I find out what is really happening here? Why does not it proceed to main page or `CustomAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication` method not called (overriding `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`)?

```
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,782][DEBUG] Checking match of request : '/j_spring_security_check'; against '/noauthorization.xhtml' - org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:177)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,782][DEBUG] Checking match of request : '/j_spring_security_check'; against '/login' - org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:177)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,782][DEBUG] Checking match of request : '/j_spring_security_check'; against '/j_spring_security_check' - org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:177)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,782][DEBUG] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /j_spring_security_check?tokenId=3e004f91-1aec-4f98-bc5c-1f49b69c209a; Attributes: [permitAll] - org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:219) 
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,782][DEBUG] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@ca1ab61a: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: node08gmgybqdzxi6l88ent9iokp01; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS - org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:348)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,782][DEBUG] Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@75a450d1, returned: 1 - org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:66)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,782][DEBUG] Authorization successful - org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:243)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,782][DEBUG] RunAsManager did not change Authentication object - org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:256)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,782][DEBUG] /j_spring_security_check?tokenId=3e004f91-1aec-4f98-bc5c-1f49b69c209a reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:313)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,791][DEBUG] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@b7199c7 - org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter.writeHeaders(HstsHeaderWriter.java:169)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,791][DEBUG] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. - org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:351)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,791][DEBUG] Chain processed normally - org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
[2020-09-02 01:39:04,792][DEBUG] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed - org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.
```

I have made many changes to xml after posting question but as far as I remember,
my securityContext.xml was like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans default-lazy-init="true"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.authentication" />



    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <custom-filter ref="customAuthenticationFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/templates/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        .
        .
        <intercept-url pattern="/ui/ordinary" access="denyAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/ui/ordinary/" access="denyAll" />
        .
        .

        <intercept-url pattern="/ui/ordinary/**"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ORDINARY','ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR','ROLE_ROOT')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/ui/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/noauthorization.xhtml"  access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**"                     access="denyAll" />
        

        <form-login login-page='/login.xhtml'
            username-parameter="j_username" 
            password-parameter="j_password" 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml"
            always-use-default-target="false" 
            default-target-url="/ui/ordinary/list.xhtml"   />
            
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/ui/ordinary/noauthorization.xhtml" />
        
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/login.xhtml?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />  
        
        <csrf disabled="true" />    

        <session-management  invalid-session-url="/login.xhtml"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customSpringAuthentication" />
    </authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationFilter"
               class="com.mayapp.authentication.CustomAuthenticationFilter" p:postOnly="false"  p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>
        <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sessionFixationAttackHandler"/>
    </beans:bean>
   <beans:bean id="successHandler"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/ui/ordinary/list.xhtml"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="failureHandler"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.xhtml?login_error=true"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="customSpringAuthentication" class="com.mayapp.authentication.CustomSpringAuthentication"/>
    
    
    <beans:bean id="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.mayapp.authentication.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <!-- beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.xhtml" /-->
        <beans:constructor-arg value="/login.xhtml"/>
    </beans:bean>
    
    <beans:bean id="sessionFixationAttackHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Show your Spring Security configuration.

Comment: CSRF protection is turned on by default in the spring security 5.x line. try turning off  csrf protection if the problem goes away,  then  figure out what changes need to me made to enable csrf for your app.

Comment: CSRF was explicity disabled in my securityContext.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerious experiments, I was able to solve the problem.

I removed

```
<intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll" />
```

And the most important thing solving it was adding "setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher" in my token filter's constructor as below:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter() {
        super();
        // Because by default value of postOnly is true in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
        super.setPostOnly(false);
        super.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/j_spring_security_check","GET") );
    }
    
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
       .
       .
    }
}
```

Thank to all guys who kindly asked me for more details to help me. I am appreciated